# Highlight cell on table (css/html) on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a website using php, css and javascript, and I have a question about how to highlight a cell (table) when I click on it? For example I have a table 3x7 and when I click on position 2x2 this position should be highlighted with a color, and if i click again in same cell it goes back, If i click many cell, all of them should be highlighted.

Thanks in advance.

```
<table border='2' cellpadding='5' align='center'>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use event delegation, where you add an `addEventListener` to the `table` and then use the event `target`, here `e.target` to detect which `td` were clicked.

Then toggle a class on the `td` to e.g. highlite them.

Stack snippet

```js
var table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('highlite')
})
```

```css
td.highlite {
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<table border='2' cellpadding='5' align='center'>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: How can I export it to eclipse? i try to run it there but is not working. I have a ccs file, a javascript file and php file in eclipse. Thanks in advance

Comment: @FranklinDavidMaciasAvellan That is an entirely different question, and is too big to answer with a comment. Please accept this answer and post a new with that requirement, so someone with better knowledge in Eclipse can answer that, as I can't. And make use of my answer when posting that new question.

Comment: Hello @LGSon sorry for the late reply I was busy, The code works well, I wrote on eclipse i had some errors but i fixed them. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

let's make it a bit easier with jQuery

css:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

js:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
})
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L5yuc1eg/

Comment: It is not easier with jQuery, as you can see in my answer.

Comment: love jQuery, love Pure JS even more :)

Comment: @LGSon: I like your answer. But regarding DOM handling, I still see using jQuery is much easier for everyone than pure js :)